# Set cursor at the end of dynamically changed contenteditable html tag

Tags: jquery

In my admin section i have a "edit" button

when edit clicked, the content should be editable

Demo Code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a onblur="noteditable(this);" >DisplayName</a>
        <span onclick="return editables(this);" >edit</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onblur="noteditable(this);" >DisplayName</a>
        <span onclick="return editables(this);" >edit</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
editables = function (Tabs) {
    $(Tabs).prev().attr('contenteditable', 'true').focus(); 
}

noteditable = function (Tabs) {
    $(Tabs).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2VJ5/)**</kbd>

> **Question:** how to make the cursor at the end ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
$.fn.focusEnd = function() {
    $(this).focus();
    var tmp = $('<span />').appendTo($(this)),
        node = tmp.get(0),
        range = null,
        sel = null;

    if (document.selection) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(node);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    tmp.remove();
    return this;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilsreeni/K2Kun/3/